# Can we get eddystone uid on monitoring beacons using altbeacon?

Tags: android, react-native, ibeacon, altbeacon, eddystone

I have been using altbeacon in react native app for ibeacon detection and need to feed uuids in order to get region uuid when regionDidEnter/ regionDidExit event is detected. Using altbeaconfor eddystone will I have to do the same or will I get all details without feeding.

My reference library was https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager

Answer (score 2):

If you use monitoring with a wildcard region like this: `new Region("my identifier",null,null,null)` the monitoring callback will not tell you the Eddystone-UID detected. Two options:

1. Construct a multiple Region objects and start monitoring for each with each Region objects set to the Edfustone-UID identifier you are looking for, e.g. `new Region("Eddystone region 1","0x0102030405060708090a",null,null)`. When you get the `didEnterRegion` callback, the Region paramater will tell you which matched.
2. Start ranging with `startRangingBeaconsInRegion(...)`.  The `didRaneBeaconsInRegion(...)` callback contains a list of all the matched beacons and tells you all of their identifiers.  This works even for the wildcard region described above.

Comment: It would work great on Android but does eddystone monitoring have limitations on monitoring regions like in iBeacon(can monitor only 20 regions)?

Comment: On Android there are no limitations (within reason) on the number of regions that may be monitored.  If you start monitoring thousands of regions, performance will be slower.  And with the Android Beacon Library, if you monitor more than 50 regions, the library will no longer maintain state between app restarts, meaning you will get an *extra* entry notification each time the app restarts when a beacon is in the vicinity.  But it will still work just fine for your purposes.

Comment: My use case contains triggering actions as per entry and exit whenever user enters a venue, like popping a notifications "Welcome to XYZ place" when the app is killed or in background(i made android service for that) but I think the number of venues exceed 50 easily I guess. Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: Sure, you can just track your own state of each region in app level code (and only execute the entry code on didEnterRegion if the last known state of the region according to your app was outside the region.)

Comment: But for that I should be able to receive didEnterRegion/Exit events right? I get the regions to be monitored by making an API call, the number of regions exceed 50 here, so how do I monitor for al these regions? as iOS has a hard limit of 20 and android loses state after 50? I need to monitor as when i detect a beacon I send UUID while making the API call.

Comment: Yes, you can start monitoring for 100+ regions.  There is no limit.  Try it -- it works, I promise!

Comment: Great thanks!, We're talking about using altbeacon for iBeacon on iOS and Android right?

Comment: Uh, the question title asks about the Eddystone format, so my answer is specific to that.  And I took "AltBeacon" in the title to mean the use of the "Android Beacon Library" as hosted by the AltBeacon project and used internally by the react-native-beacons-manager.  If you are asking something else, please clarify the question.  The answers above really only apply to Android as react-native-beacons-manager only supports ranging a single Eddystone region with no monitoring.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity! I understood your answer, altbeacon supports monitoring in eddystone for my use case, but does altbeacon support iBeacon monitoring with more that 50 regions in android? And also could you give me some alternative for ios monitoring for >50 regions

Comment: Yes, the Android Beacon Library supports monitoring > 50 iBeacon regions.  The alternative for iOS is to use ranging instead.  On iOS ranging regions are unlimited.

Comment: Yes but they dont support didEnterRegion/Exit events in ranging and I need it for my specific use case. If someone enters a shop or exits I would need to trigger actions